# Guava, Objects/MoreObjects overloading to avoid autoboxing.

Tags: java, guava

Guava Objects(deprecated) or MoreObjects implements the ToStringHelper class using builder pattern, the add() function is implemented for both primitive type and Object:

```
public ToStringHelper add(String name, @Nullable Object value)
public ToStringHelper add(String name, boolean value) 
public ToStringHelper add(String name, char value) 
... (other primitive type)
```

the class works fine even without the overloading of primitive types, because the autoboxing converts and calls the add(String, Object) function.

So my question is the reason of using overloading for all primitives to avoid autoboxing?

1.repetitive autoboxing can be a huge overhead, but for most use case, this is not going to happen. Effective Java item 49, prefer primitive types to boxed primitives.

2.Efffective Java, Item 41, P193,

> A safe conservative policy is never to export two overloadings with the same number of parameters.

the ToStringHelper example is a obvious violation of this policy. The author goes on to talk about in class ObjectOutputStream, different primitives has their own function: writeBoolean(boolean), writeInt(int) ... I was never able to understand the advantage of using different name to avoid overloading for this specific example, why is it good?

Any input will be welcomed.

Comment: I think that the reason why it's OK to violate #2 here is that there is no "broken" case - all of the primitive type cases do exactly the same thing as the corresponding boxed type would - it's not like it's fine for bool but you get an exception for `char`. There are primitive methods overloads for all of the primitive types on `String.valueOf`, which are able to do the conversion without the creation of the boxed object, so it makes sense to avoid unnecessary object creation (EJ Item 5).

Comment: Immediately above the 'safe conservative policy' line is the less conservative statement 'avoid **confusing** uses of overloading'. It then says 'Exactly what constitutes a confusing use of overloading is up for some debate'. I don't think this is confusing - ToStringHelper is implemented to work like you'd expect, for everything you pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesistate to give this as an answer because it is second-guessing the Guava language designers. They might be able to give you a definite answer, but this is what I surmise:

Shortly before the "conservative policy" on Effective Java 2nd Ed Page 193 is the statement:

> Avoid **confusing** uses of overloading

Whilst it then goes on to say

> Exactly what constitutes a confusing use of overloading is up for some debate

I think that this is not a confusing use of overloading. I claim this because the logical behaviour of the class is identical to if it were simply implemented as:

```
public ToStringHelper add(String name, @Nullable Object value)
// No primitive overloads.
```

However, there are other suggestions in EJ which come into play. One is Item 49 on page 20, another is Item 5, "Avoid creating unnecessary objects".

It's not necessary to create the boxed primitives because there are overloads of `String.valueOf(...)` which handle each of the primitive types, inevitably more efficiently than boxing them and calling `toString()`.

Bear in mind that Guava was written for Google first, and then they open-sourced it. At the scale that Google works, the difference between using the primitive type and creating the boxed type, calling `toString()` and destroying the object is going to be measurable.

Adding these overloads will give a performance win without the caller really needing to do anything to get it. On the other hand, if there were differently-named overloads (e.g. `addChar`, `addBoolean`), you actually would have to consciously choose which one you invoke, and likely many invocations would lazily select the `Object` overload, because, hey, it works. Keeping the same names allows it to work transparently.

---

There are a lot of other examples in Guava of avoiding the unnecessary creation of objects via overloads. For instance, `ImmutableList` has the `of` static factory method, overloaded for zero, one, two, ..., eleven elements, and then everything else is handled by the variadic overload.

It *could* be implemented simply as `ImmutableList.of(T... elements)`, but that would require the implicit creation of the variadic array each time, which must be defensively copied internally in order to guarantee the immutability of the list.

As such, these overloads provide the opportunity to build the list a bit more efficiently. As a user of the class, you probably never notice this, however.

Comment: it is a good point that the add() function is used on a very large scale, the example of ImmutableList is right to the point, I have to check it out

Answer (score 2):

I made the change to Objects to add the extra overloads. **Yes, it was done to avoid auto-boxing.** We occasionally do see problems with performance sensitive code and auto-boxing (another API we often get complaints about w.r.t. autoboxing is Preconditions, but we haven't made the change there yet).

FWIW, here's the [original bug report](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=740).